# How to run Logout method present in another controller- Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have a view `include/Header.php` in which I have this part

```
#This is to display the `Menu list` if the user has logged in else dont show this `Menu list`

if($this->Membership->checkLogin()){
echo "<li><a href='http://localhost/nams/Login/Logout'>Logout</a></li>";      
}
```

After successful login I redirect the controller `Login` to `Application`.

In the `Application` controller when it runs `index` I am loading the `include/Header` view, and the menu is shown.

The anchor link is `http://localhost/nams/Login/Logout`.

From the controller `Application`, when I click on the link, it shows `404` error.

What is the reason for this error ?

Comment: If you go to `http://localhost/nams/Login/Logout` directly through URL, do you get a 404 ?

Comment: Yes..I dont know what am I doing wrong.. I